# How to get the value of t

Tags: linear-algebra

For each number t, consider the triangle T with corners at, A = (1, 2, 3), B = (1, 0, −2),
C = (t, t, 1).

For which value of t does T have a right angle at A?

I know how it has to do with AB*CD = something

Rest i don't know how to solve this??

Comment: Maybe use that the Pythagoras theorem works only for right-angle triangles?

Comment: One way is to use distance formula along with Baudhayan theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented earlier, you can use the Pythagoras theorem: for a right angle we know that $a^2+b^2=c^2$. We can find the lengths first:

$AB = \sqrt{0^2+2^2+5^2} = \sqrt{29}$

$BC = \sqrt{(1-t)^2 + t^2 +3^2} = \sqrt{10-2t+2t^2}$

$AC = \sqrt{(1-t)^2 + (2-t)^2 + 2^2} = \sqrt{9-6t+2t^2}$

Now we can plug in these values for $a,b$ and $c$. We want a right angle at $A$ so we need to solve: $(AB)^2 + (AC)^2 = (BC)^2$.
This gives: $t=7$.

Comment: Consider to accept this as a final answer of your problem, thanks!

Comment: Moenaar Why did you use the square-root for AB for example?

Comment: To find the distance between two points in two dimensions say $A=(-2,1)$ and $B=(1,3)$ you can use again Pythagoras to find that $AB = \sqrt{(-2-1)^2+(1-3)^2} = \sqrt{9+4} = \sqrt{13}$. (make a quick graph, enter the points if you do not see this immediately) For 3 dimensions the distance can be found similarly: $A=(a_1, a_2, a_3), B=(b_1, b_2,b_3) \rightarrow AB = \sqrt{(a_1-b_1)^2+(a_2-b_2)^2+(a_3-b_3)^2}$. Hope this explains it

Comment: i get it to -7.5 when i use wolfram-alpha?

Comment: what is -7.5? t?

Comment: Molnaar Yes i get t = -7.5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131189/discussion-between-john-and-tobias-molenaar).